# xml substitutionGroups - which elements are included in the subst group?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe, xsd-1.1

I am dealing with a complex set of xsd files, deeply nested, with deep relations/extensions between types.

One of those xsds defines an abstract element and a substitution group is available for it

```
<xsd:element name="myElem" type="MyAbstractType" abstract="true"/> 

<xsd:element name="aaa" substitutionGroup="myElem">  

<xsd:element name="bbb" substitutionGroup="myElem">  

<!--... more elements follow, some are extending aaa,bbb,myElem...etc -->
```

I checked all the imported xsds, there are no other elements which contain `substitutionGroup="myElem"`, only `aaa` and `bbb` contain it.

So, as far as I understand, only `aaa` and `bbb` can substitute `myElem`. Period. No other element.

However, to my surprise, I got an xml, which contains elements somehow related to `aaa`, `bbb` (via multiple layers of extensions) and this xml seems valid (I checked with multiple validators).

So it seems that I do not fully understand the substitution mechanism.
What elements other than `aaa` and `bbb` could possibly interfere with the substitution mechanism in such way to make that xml valid?

My question:

How is the exhaustive set of allowed substitutions determined?

Is maybe the xsd extension somehow involved in the substitution mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

op. here: turns out I had missed some transitive substitutions, e.g.

```
<xsd:element name="ccc" substitutionGroup="aaa">
```

which means that

element `ccc` is also a valid substitution for the 'root' `myElem`